# Can I use membership information in a mail?

Tags: civimember, email, tokens

We are using Memberships including some custom fields to save additional information (e.g. the name of a specific beneficiary supported through that individual membership).

Mailings through CiviCRM can include Tokens to insert contact-specific information like name and address. However, there are no tokens available for membership information.

I guess this is technically more challenging because mail is sent to a contact and a contact can have more than one membership. Is there some feature, extension or workaround to send mail "to a membership" or otherwise insert individual membership information in the text?

Answer (score 4):

Eileen did an extension that added some membership tokens to deal with contacts having multiple membership and which do work from 'contact'

{latestcurrentmembership.end_date}

{latestcurrentmembership.allend_date}

https://civicrm.org/extensions/nzcofuzioncivitoken

please let us know how you get on with it

Comment: I have the same question for a membership custom field that i created. I did install the Fuzion extension for membership tokens and it works great. But for custom fields created under memberships i did not find how to insert this field in e-mail.

Comment: While that is a useful addition to the issue, its not an answer and should be a comment instead, probably to the petednz answer

Comment: You'd have to create your own tokens for your custom fields.

Comment: In response to the last paragraph of the question you have to select as memberships not contacts if you want to use these tokens so that gets round any issue of multiple memberships.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10469)