# Additional info required on mail tokens

Tags: civimember, tokens, 4.6

Was wondering if anyone could help. We need some mail tokens adding for membership details and event details so we can send out mass mails with personalised information in.

This isn't in civicrm as standard, wonder how other people have got around this?

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you trying to send email?

Comment: Have you checked http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens

Comment: Just trying to send emals, like at the start of the month, mass email all members that are due for renewal that month with a reminder letter etc. This needs to have membership details etc on them.

Jitendra, I have looked at that but it doesnt have what I need in it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you are asking similar question to [this one](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2460/can-i-use-membership-information-in-a-mail) but my answer is the same so hopefully it helps you move forward.

Eileen did an [extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/nzcofuzioncivitoken) that added some membership tokens to deal with contacts having multiple membership and which do work from 'contact'

{latestcurrentmembership.end_date}

{latestcurrentmembership.allend_date}

please let us know how you get on with it

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Peter's great recommendation, check out Jamie McClelland's Summary Fields extension [here](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) for some of the info you may want to be adding as tokens to e-mails.

Answer (score 1):

Scott,

If you are looking to create a token with specific event or membership information related to the contact, you'll need to write some custom code.

Here's a blog Coleman wrote on how to create your own tokens.
https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/create-your-own-tokens-fun-and-profit

You can probably ask Coleman directly if you go to CiviCON in London next week. :)
https://london2015.civicrm.org/